# How can I enable Fidder capture for a process running as a different user?

Tags: c#, fiddler

I have a process running as a different user on my machine that I want to capture HTTP (and HTTPS) traffic with. When I start Fiddler, it only captures processes from my user account.

I'm interested in doing this for both applications I build and applications that I do not have the source code for, as well as instructions for native and .NET applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Fiddler docs](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/CaptureTrafficFromADifferentAccount):

**C# Applications (you have a few options):**

1) Edit the `machine.config` file:

```
<!-- Force Fiddler for all .NET processes, including those running under service accounts -->  
<system.net>
 <defaultProxy>
  <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
 </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

2) Edit the program's `app.config` file using the settings above

3) Specify the proxy on a `WebRequest` object:

```
objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
objRequest.Proxy= new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

**Native Applications (Windows Vista or above):**

For Windows 7 and earlier, use the `netsh` that matches the architecture of your application (32 or 64 bit)

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:8888
```

When done, you can clear the proxy by:

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```